# How do I find Endpoint Data in Drupal 8

Tags: api, drupal-8, drupal-modules, endpoint

I was handed a D9 site.  Have not touched Drupal since D7.  Anyway, we have a client that is sending data to an endpoint on our sided.  Here are the comments/notes that I got:

> MarktCom populates some hidden vars on their site and sends them to the endpoint like this `/Casingo/api/post`
> Casingo gets those values and contacts MarktCom's api with the clientID.
> MarktCom then returns the member data

I realize this is probably a stupid question, but how do I find/get/see the data that MarktCom sent?  I have gone thru the custom module.  I see the endpoint url (above), I see the **api data path** and **api domain**.  but I don't see the data when I dig into the directory (i'm assuming it probably a .json file.).  I can see the ultimate .csv files that are being created from the data, but not the actual data.

Lots has happen due to the issues of the past couple of years, so getting to anyone on their side that knows what going has been hard/impossible.  The overarching issue is that the .csv file, a couple of months ago, the data/info started all duplicating, so I want to see what we are getting so I can determine where to start fix.

And ideas on how I can investigate this would be much appreciated.

Comment: It seems to me like you are simply going to have to follow the trail of what happens in the custom module. Maybe start by taking a look at what is called when the `/Casingo/api/post` endpoint is hit. I am not sure why you would expect to see a ,json file. If I was to guess, the mention of "Member data" would lead me to believe that maybe the module is manipulating users in the drupal site with whatever data it is getting from "MarktCom"

Comment: this is so weird, i never see the data in the endpoint on our side.  I am going to reverse my logic - i am going to get the .csv file that is generated from that endpoint data and just use python to clean up the file, remove the dups and then rewrite.